# set laravel blade value in html

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, laravel-blade

I have 2 pages in laravel blade. one is master layout. 
**layouts.master**

```
    <html>
        <body>
           <div>
                  <iframe src="@yield('content')" name="search"></iframe>
  </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Second one is**

```
  @extends('layouts.master')
     @section('content')
        <p>This is my body content.</p>
    @endsection
```

But the second one is not displayed through iframe **src** value. how to set the **src value** of second page in **iframe**

Comment: there's must be URL in src field of iframe. you are putting whole <p> in it.

Comment: You don't even need the iframe for it. Why don't you just write <div>@yield('content')</div>

Comment: Yes I tried it in <div>. Its working

Comment: I am having the above use-case, I need to to have an iframe in the master layout. Is it possible in laravel 5.7 to set the iframe's src as another blade view?